# How can I create a subtype of Error to throw it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to throw my own kind of error, so that when catching I can call `if(instanceof DatabaseError)` and handle it my own way.

```
export class DatabaseError extends Error {
    constructor(...args: string[] | undefined[]) {
        super(...args);
        this.name = "DatabaseError"
    }
}

const err: DatabaseError = new DatabaseError(`Message`);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(err));
```

However, it looks like for all intents and purposes, `err` is not an instance of DatabaseError. The log returns `Error {}`, and instanceof DatabaseError returns false. What have I done wrong, and what is the correct way to introduce new Errors so that I can handle them differenty? Or should I create an object that doesn't inherit from Error?

Here is the tsconfig.json I am using:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6", /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs", /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true, /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "esModuleInterop": true, /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true, /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to `console.log(err)`, not just its prototype?

Comment: How are you transpiling your TypeScript? There might be some incompatibilities with subclassing builtins in older environments (or code produced for them), but the code you posted works as expected out of the box.

Comment: I am not sure which options are relevant, but in my tsconfig I have target=es5, module=commonjs, strict=true, esModuleInterop=true, skipLibCheck=true, forceConsistentCasingInFileNames = true. Are any of those wrong? I run it with npx ts-node --files ./src/backend/index.ts

Comment: target = ES5 will most likely be the culprit. Look at the transpiler output to understand what's actually happening (maybe [edit] your question to include it). Try using ES6 as the target and compare.

Comment: You are correct, ES6 fixed it! Could you post it as the anwser so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are You sure you tried `instanceof` ?

```js
export class DatabaseError extends Error {
    constructor(...args: string[] | undefined[]) {
        super(...args);
        this.name = "DatabaseError"
    }
}

const err: DatabaseError = new DatabaseError(`Message`);
err instanceof DatabaseError // true
```

You can try this conde in your console, just don't forget remove type anotations.
It works for me as expected.

You don't need to use `getPrototypeOf`

Comment: Interesting. Chrome dev console says true. Node console too. But if I run it in my program it says false. Could this be a typescript related bug maybe?

Comment: I don't think so. TS compiles to JS, it does not replaces [instanceof] keyword